# Can I use subobjects of a StaticResource?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, staticresource, converters

Feeling a bit bored of cut and pasting converters between projects at the moment.

Is there any way I can use a single Converters object which has converters as fields/properties?

e.g. something like:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <sharedLib:Converters
        x:Key="Converters" />
</Application.Resources>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Target, Converter={StaticResource Converters.MakeAllCaps}}" />
```

If not, then does anyone have any suggestions for how the converters might otherwise be bulk imported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define all your converters in a resource dictionary like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:loc="...">

    <loc:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibility" />
    <loc:MakeAllCapsConverter x:Key="MakeAllCaps" />

    <!-- Define all the common converters here -->
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Now you can import this resource dictionary anywhere via `MergedDictionaries` like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Converters.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Target, Converter={StaticResource MakeAllCaps}}" />
```